# LLDB autocompletion not working (Lubuntu)

Tags: autocomplete, llvm, lldb

Auto-completion is not working when I hit TAB in lldb session.
I'm trying to figure out why.

**Steps to reproduce the issue:**
start the terminal -> start lldb -> digit bre<kbd>TAB</kbd>

```
$ lldb
(lldb) bre< TAB >
```

When I hit the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key it's not completing to "breakpoint", instead it's inserting a tab-space.

Could it be an incompatibility of `lldb` in `lxterminal`, or some miss configuration?

Any ideas that could help me figure out what is going on and how can I get it working?

Thanks for any help.

-- System information --

```
VirtualBox 5.2.0 r118431(Qt5.6.3)
host os: OSX 10.13.4
guest os: Lubuntu 17.10
lldb version: 4.0.1
```

NOTE: lldb autocompletion works perfectly in Terminal in the Host OS.

-- Searches I've already done --
on DuckDuckgo and Stackoverflow.com (couldn't find anything useful)

1. "Lubuntu" "lldb" "lxterminal" autocompletion not working
2. "lldb" "lxterminal" autocompletion
3. "lldb" "lxterminal"
4. "lldb" autocompletion not working

**-- UPDATE --**
Maybe it is not an lxterminal issue with lldb. Just now I installed gnome-terminal and I'm having the same behaviour.
Could it be something in the Lubuntu OS or VirtualBox?

Comment: lldb uses editline, and completion is done by lldb's adding an editline command (called `lldb-complete`) and binding it to the tab key.  But this is done before reading in your .editrc file.  Is there any chance you have a .editrc file that remaps tab?  That would override lldb's command.

Comment: In my home directory there is no .editrc file.
When you as if I have a .editrc file that remaps tab, i suppose you mean a ~/.editrc with some command like "lldb:bing ^I ....". After you comment I found https://www.mankier.com/5/editrc and http://www.stuartcarnie.com/2012/06/lldb-vi-mode-and-tab-completion.html, then I created a .editrc file and put 2 lines "lldb:bind ^I lldb_complete" and "lldb:bind ^P ed-command". The behaviour is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Removed ed purged lldb-4.0.
Installed lldb-6.0 from llvm repository

see: https://apt.llvm.org

```
    # uninstall  lldb-4.0 completely
    $sudo apt purge lldb-4.0
    $sudo apt autoremove
    $sudo apt autoclean

    # install lldb-6.0 from llvm repository for ubuntu 18 Bionic
    $sudo apt-add-repository "deb http://apt.llvm.org/bionic/ llvm-toolchain-bionic-6.0 main"
    $sudo apt update
    $sudo apt install lldb-6.0

    # create lldb that points to the same file pointed by lldb-6.0
    $cd /usr/bin/
    $sudo ln -s ../lib/llvm-6.0/bin/lldb lldb
```

now everything works regularly